# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Почему мне показывает следующую ошибку, хотя запрос правильный?

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in X:\home\localhost\www\kbm\adm\functions.php on line 100

```
function get_orders($pdo) {
    $list = null;
    $style = null;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM orders'); //линия 100
    $stmt->execute();
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        if ($row['status'] == 'new') {
            $style = '';
        } else {
            $style = 'style="color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);text-shadow: none;"';
        }
        $list .= '<li><label '.$style.'><input type="radio" name="order" value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['id'].'. '.$row['userName'].' <sup><sub>'.date('d.m.y H:i', $row['timeOrder']).'</sub></sup></label></li>';
    }
    echo $list;
    $pdo = null;
}
```

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке прочитайте.

Comment: Не может вызвать ф-цию prepare()

Comment: ...вызвать у чего?

Comment: У вас глобальная переменная `$pdo` скорее всего на момент вызова функции `get_orders()` еще не определена. А если так, то она равна `null`. Как думаете, конструкция следующего вида как в примере: `null->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders");` верна? Я советую вам отказаться от глобальных переменных.

Comment: Но тогда как мне быть без глобальных? Я иного способа не знаю.

Comment: @Ezdrael Ну так узнайте! Передавайте эту переменную параметром, например. А глобальные переменные - это плохо, очень

Comment: @rjhdby, как передать переменную параметром?

Comment: `function get_orders($pdo) {` в объявлении функции. `get_orders($pdo)` при вызове.

Comment: @VenZell а ошибка ""Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in"" не пропала

Comment: Ну а вы переменную `$pdo` объявили как надо? Покажите обновленный код. Где вы объявляете переменную `$pdo` и где передаете.

Comment: @VenZell ну вот...  function get_orders($pdo) {
  $list = null;
  $style = null;
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM orders'); //линия 100
  $stmt->execute();
  foreach ($stmt as $row) {
   if ($row['status'] == 'new') {
    $style = '';
   } else {
    $style = 'style="color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);text-shadow: none;"';
   }
   $list .= '<li><label '.$style.'><input type="radio" name="order" value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['id'].'. '.$row['userName'].' <sup><sub>'.date('d.m.y H:i', $row['timeOrder']).'</sub></sup></label></li>';
  }
  echo $list;
  $pdo = null;
 }

Comment: @VenZell как вы в формате кода текст вставляете?

Comment: Обновите свой вопрос, а не пишите в комментариях код. К тому же я не вижу здесь того, как вы вызываете функцию и как объявляете переменную `$pdo`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61979/discussion-between-ezdrael-and-venzell).